# Sharepoint 2013 Install problems

Tags: sql, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to install Sharepoint 2013 on my test SERVER 2012 Server.

I have pre installed all the prerequisites but when i run the installer it says AppFabric is not configured correctly but i have set this up and also configured the AppFabric Cache.

I have unistalled this and tried using the sharepoint prerequisite installer but it skips the AppFabric installation.

I have installed all the roles needed for server 2012 to be a DC and have also installed SQL 2013 on the server.

The sharepoint installer keeps saying AppFabric is not configured correctly!

Very frustrating...i cannot proceed with any other installation until this is installed.

Any help would be greatful..

Comment: Hope this helps you

http://www.spjeff.com/2012/07/19/fixed-sharepoint-2013-setup-error-appfabric-is-not-correctly-configured/

Comment: If not, try here http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/20ccc1c7-240a-4a87-aeec-8535377c5d3e/sharepoint-2013-installtion-error-in-windows-appfabric and here http://www.sathishtk.com/blog/post/2012/08/17/SharePoint-2013-installation-error-Windows-AppFabric-11-1603-error.aspx

Comment: Hi Tried all of this and still no luck!

Comment: When researching best practices for installing SharePoint, I found several sources that stated to NOT use the SharePoint installer. Including this site/video: Don't Suck at SharePoint: [https://www.slideshare.net/benjaminniaulin/dont-suck-at-sharepoint-avoid-the-common-mistakes](https://www.slideshare.net/benjaminniaulin/dont-suck-at-sharepoint-avoid-the-common-mistakes)
Crazy huh? Instead, it's recommended to use script(s) to install it.

Comment: This site is practically used by everyone. It used to be a program that you installed, but now they moved it to a website that will generate the scripts for you.

[AutospInstaller](https://autospinstaller.com/)

The Guide on that site is extremely helpful as well

[SharePoint AutospInstaller Guide](https://autospinstaller.com/Guide)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you, see that the string does not have any space, prerequisiteInstaller.exe /appfabric:Z:\Softwares**Sharepoint 2013PreRequisite**\WindowsServerAppFabricSetup_x64.exe, look this **Sharepoint 2013PreRequisite** remove the space. Look this link[1](https://sharepointjim.com/2014/09/20/windows-server-app-fabric-is-not-correctly-configured-sharepoint-2013-setup-errors/)